# Matching words from a dictionary(an external txt file) with an article (another external txt file)

Tags: c

I've managed to store the article into heap, but what should I do with the dictionary? I tried using **strcpy(tempArticle[i], dictionary);**  but it didn't seem to work? would someone give me a hint as to what to do in the next step?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void spellCheck(char article[], char dictionary[]) {
    int len = strlen(article) + 1;
    int i;
    char* tempArticle;
    tempArticle = malloc(len);

    if (tempArticle == NULL) {
        printf("spellcheck: Memory allocation failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        tempArticle[i] = tolower(article[i]);

        i=0;

    while (tempArticle[i] != '\0'){
        if (tempArticle[i] >= 33 && tempArticle[i] <= 64)
            tempArticle[i] = ' ';
        i++;
    }

    strcpy(tempArticle[i], dictionary);

    printf("%s", tempArticle);

    free(tempArticle);
}
```

Comment: We could be more helpful if we knew what you are trying to achieve here. The name of the function suggests some comparison rather than just copying. Right now this won't even compile, since tempArray[i] is not a (char*) [or compile with warning and crash at runtime]

Comment: why isn't tempArticle a char? I have declared it to be char* tempArticle;

Comment: tempArticle[i] *is* a char. strcpy() expects two pointers to char (char*). 'strcpy(tempArticle, dictionary)' is valid (but you probably want strcmp().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet will be to figure out your algorithm first, and *then* code it up.

In other words, get a whiteboard, a piece of paper or fire up a text editor and write down, in plain language, the steps you would go through to compare the article against the dictionary.  You might start with something very simple, like:

- Go through each word in the article, and see if it is in the dictionary.  If is it not, add it to a list of misspelled words.
- Print the list of misspelled words.

Then you have to break each of the complicated bits down further - for example, "see if a single word is in the dictionary" needs to be broken down.  (By the way, each of the self-contained "complicated bits" like this is a good candidate for a separate function in the resulting code).

At that point, you will find that converting what you've come up with into code will be a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using strcpy(tempArticle[i], dictionary); but it didn't seem to work?

tempArticle[i] is an array position and dictionary is an array..

Use array for storing array.. hopefully that will solve the issue.. Right now  i guess only the 1st character in dictionary will be stored in temparticle..

Comment: Regarding the last strcpy(): strcpy() iterates over the input string. Thus, if the above even compiles, the result would be writing 'n' characters into some unknown memory address. *Crash*